# When and how does bool get called in this code?

Tags: c, boolean, cs50

I've been working my way through CS50 just to learn the basics of coding. I successfully made plurality of Problem Set 3, but I don't really understand how the boolean works. So the specific questions are:

1) How does the structure of the boolean work?
2) When and how does it get called?

I'm trying to understand the fundamental aspect of using this. Thanks for any help.

Here's the code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
   // TODO
   for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
   {
       if (strcmp (name, candidates[i].name) == 0)
       {
           candidates[i].votes++;
           return true;
       }
   }
    return false;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 1; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[0].votes < candidates[i].votes)
        candidates[0].votes = candidates[i].votes;
    }
    printf ("%s\n", candidates[0].name);
    for (int i = 1; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[0].votes == candidates[i].votes)
        printf ("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: `bool` is a type (like `int` or `float` or `char`). It only has two values: 0 (false) or 1 (true).

Answer (score 6):

> how does bool get called in this code?

You have some significant misunderstanding of terminology here. Asking "how does bool get called" doesn't make any sense. Let me clarify some of this for you:

1. `bool` is what we call a "data type". Other data types are `int` and `char`. These define the meaning of a value in memory. For example, `int` is positive and negative whole numbers, `char` is letters and symbols, and `bool` is true or false.
2. Functions are things that we "call". More specifically, a function is a section of code to perform a specific task. We "call" the function to make it perform that task. This is why it doesn't make sense to ask "when does bool get called". We never "call bool" because `bool` is a data type not a function.
3. When we declare a function, we have to provide 3 pieces of information: the functions name, the list of inputs (or more accurately the types of each of the inputs), and the type of the result of the function (called the "return type"). When you write `bool vote(string name);`, this declares a function named `vote` that takes a `string` as an input and returns a `bool`.

   The confusion might be because we use `bool` as part of the definition of a function. In the example above, we are just saying that the result of calling the `vote()` function is either true or false.

With all this in mind, we can talk about when the `vote()` function is called. To figure that out, you just look through the code for all the occurrences of the word `vote`. If you do so, you will find a line `if (!vote(name))`. This is where `vote()` is called. In otherwords, we tell the computer to execute the code in the `vote()` function and it returns a true or false value that is used to evaluate the condition of the if statement.

As you continue to learn programming, be sure to pay close attention to terminology. Like many other disciplines, we have our own vocabulary. In order to communicate with other programmers, you will need to use the right words. More importantly, understanding the words we use will help you understand the concepts more clearly so you can apply them yourself.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. It's starting to make more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

`bool` is a `type`, used to create a *boolean* variable, i.e. one that will be sufficient for `true/false` evaluations.  So, because `bool`  not a function it does not get *called*.

The prototype: `bool vote(string name);` indicates that the function `vote()` accepts a `string` variable as an argument, and returns a `bool` *value* (`true` or `false`) upon its return, where the value returned by the `bool` type can only be a `1` or `0`. (`TRUE` or `FALSE`) This property of `bool` is what makes the statement `if (!vote(name)){...}` possible.    This construct uses a common *shortcut* syntax to call the function, evaluate the return value and  decide on execution flow all in one line.

This could have also been written using more verbose syntax:

```
bool result = false; //'result' is created and initialized to false

result = vote(name);//function vote() is called, and assigns its return value to result.
if(result == false)
{
     printf("Invalid vote.\n");
}
```

where the `bool` variable *result* is assigned the return value of the function `vote()`.
Implied also, if the return value of `vote()` had been `true`, then the comparison statement `(result == false)` would fail, and bypass the fail message.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. It's starting to make more sense now.

Comment: @millsware - you are welcome.  I discovered a typo in my answer, and have fixed it, but just in case you read: _`bool` type can only be a `1` or `2`_  it is of course incorrect.  That has been corrected to say: `bool` type can only be a `1` or `0`

Answer (score 0):

in // Update vote totals given a new vote
you should write i < voter_count    instead of   i < candidate_count
because if you have for example 3 candidates and 100 voters you will  take in consideration just the first 3 voters and the others 97 will not be taken. So the correct code is to compare with voter count not candidate count.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it might be a bit late to comment on this (and might be a bit irrelevant to your question) but I wrote the same code as you and I encountered an issue.

So, with this code, the name of the candiate(s) who has the highest votes will be printed out twice sometimes.

I think this is because we give candidate[0] the value of candidate[i] if the votes of candidate [i] is higher than candidate [0]. But the value of candidate [i] remained the same. E.g, if we have 3 candidates (A,B,C), whose votes are (1,1,3) respectively. After running the first half of the print_winner function, our results become C(3 votes), B(1 votes), C(3 votes). Then we print out "C" as it is the name of candidate[0]. Then we run the remaining of print_winner function, we will print out "C" again as it is the name of candidate[2] whose votes is the same as candidate[0].

Please correct me if I am wrong on this. I am also just a beginner in coding :).